# Printing integers with a fixed number of zeros in C++

Tags: c++, printing, integer

The question is simple. I have messed up with **std::fixed**, **std::setprecicion**, **std::setw**, but none of them solves my problem.

If I have a integer variable equal to 1, I want it to be printed as:
**1000**

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should create a string with your number formatted into it. The C++ output routines are meant to print the actual number they're given, not something a thousand times that number.

Comment: `cout << n << "000";`

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::left` together with `std::setw` and `std::setfill` to add a number of specific fill characters on the right. Example with `std::cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::left << 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I believe it should do the job.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I wanted to print like this to show an hour format.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want it to print as 0001, not as 1000.

Look at printf / sprintf with a format string. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 1;

    printf("%04d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: I think he/she actually meant 1000 for some reason. And knowing the material involved, people here are probably gonna crucify you over using `printf` in an answer to a C++ question (not justifying this of course).

Comment: It is meant to 1000. Sorry for the confusion. It is for an hour format.

Comment: If it's an hour format, then you probably mean 0100. 1000 would be 10 hours. So then you could printf("%04d\n", i * 100);

Comment: @goodvibration I tend to take a pragmatic approach rather than a purist's approach. Use whatever most easily solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to print the value of your variable with 3 zeroes appended to it, you should just print the variable and then 3 zeroes.

```cpp
cout << x << "000" << endl;
```

If you need to do any computation with it, you could always just multiply it by `1000`.

```cpp
int y = x * 1000;
cout << y << endl;
```

Keep in mind that this may cause an overflow, though...